# Auto Match Criteria in Google Multiplayer Sample BittonClicker Game for android

Tags: android

I changed auto-match criteria configuration as per my requirement

```
void startQuickGame() {
  final int MIN_OPPONENTS = 1, MAX_OPPONENTS = 3;
  Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(MIN_OPPONENTS,
  MAX_OPPONENTS, 0);
  RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
  rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
  rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
  rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);

 getGamesClient().createRoom(rtmConfigBuilder.build());
 }
```

but game still starts after 1(one) opponent (as set MIN_OPPONENT=1) . onRoomConnected() callback is called right after 1 opponent and did not wait for further opponents (as we set in MAX_OPPONETS.=3).

i also tried with my own waiting room UI and add a time delay. after that delay game will starts with available opponents within min and max opponent limit. but this will never happen ...
i am confused. :(

anyone can help ???

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775194/room-configuration-did-not-work-properly-in-google-real-time-multiplayer-service/16802177#16802177

Comment: so thanks @BrunoOliveira . i have tried this.. i explain this with a test case. i set-up room configuration MIN_OPPONENTS = 3, MAX_OPPONENTS = 3. then i install game on 2 different devices. and click to create room. now both devices shows up their custom waiting room UI with only one player(player itself with no opponents). google pay service cant find them for each other. if i install this game on 2 more devices and click on game start button.. then all devices suddenly receives a collective  call backs with 3 opponents on all devices. it did not search and notify opponents one by one.

Comment: 2nd test case. if i setup MIN_OPPONENTS = 1, MAX_OPPONENTS = 3. then if i install game on 3 different devices and start game at same time with My own waiting room UI. then google play service finds one opponent for  one player and joins both in a room with onPeerConnected() callback and right after onRoomConnected() call callback received(which means room is fully connected as per reguirement) without searching and finding 2nd opponent which is live in that time and waiting for opponents. google play service  ideally should wait and search for 2nd opponent possibility.

Comment: Same issue hopefully @BrunoOliveira responds to this

Comment: Have you found anything about this problem? I'm right now at the same exact point you were when you posted it.